# Bootstrap navbar collapse menu not working in mobiles

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying for a long time to fix this for a long time i have ran through my code multiple times have kept jquery files before bootstrap files and still they just don't work!

***(I am new to programming so please forgive me if this is a silly error, Thank you!)***

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>">love</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>about">About</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>blog">Help</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>blog">Other</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div>
<!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

For data-target use an ID. And the same ID on the "collapse navbar-collapse" class div.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>">love</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>about">About</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>blog">Help</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>blog">Other</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div>
<!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Order your `jquery` and `bootstrap` in correct order. Check below snippet it works correctly.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>">love</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>blog">Help</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>blog">Other</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```